Romance Kung-Fu movie with hero with one arm (swordman)
It's a movie which have many episodes. It's a romance kungfu movie. The hero has a big sword and also lost one arm. If he is injured, he goes into a cave and leans on a big ice stone that can help him recover.
He has learned many types of kungfu from many masters. He also rides a big bird and if I'm not mistaken its garuda.
Does anyone know what this movie is? It had been shown either in tv7 or tv8 in Malaysia around 2007-8.

All the clues in the description seem to lead to one of Jin Yong's classics, The Return of the Condor Heroes. All of the following facts has a match:

It is a romance wuxia story
The protagonist at one point lost one of his arms
after losing his arm, he trained in a style of sword fighting that took advantage of a giant, dull, heavy sword
A giant condor became his master at one point and faithful companion afterwards. It was capable of carrying people, although it was also intelligent enough to dislike being treated as a ride
He learned multiple disciplines of martial arts. They're either formally taught, studied from manuscripts, duplicated from observation, or sometimes even stolen.
His first place of study was an ancient tomb where there was a never-melting ice bed with healing properties. It was also the dwelling place of his master and lover.

This being a popular novel, there's multiple movie and TV adaptations - so it'd be difficult to pin down a specific version that aired on a specific channel at a specific time. Hopefully the Wikipedia entry would make a good starting point to find the version you're looking for.

There was a 1967 movie called "The one armed swordsman".
Here is a link to the details
The One Armed Swordsman

On the site you link to, his sword is very small.  The question says "the hero has a big sword".

This is the original, there was also a remake made many years later, but not entirely sure of the name.

And The One Armed Boxer, also starring Jimmy Wang Yu
